# how to change the Volume of a virtual drive created by subst?

Tags: windows, subst

I'm using [subst](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491006.aspx) to create virtual drive mapping to a working folder for ease of use (I can't use [mklink](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(WS.10).aspx) as "secpol.msc" is disabled, or [new-symlink](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-SymLink-60d2531e) as power script is disabled), the Volume of the virtual drive is set the same as the physical drive where the working folder belongs to. Is there a way to change the Volume of the virtual drive?

Comment: I don't think you can. Subst options are fairly basic. What is the purpose of changing the size displayed? The underlying disk size will be unchanged.

Comment: Volume is a text label , not the size

Comment: you can try the Label command, but I have no idea how it would work with a subst. My guess is you can't have a special volume label for a subst mapping. http://www.computerhope.com/labelhlp.htm

Comment: Yeah Label doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, Mount-Points always share the name of the root drive they are located on. Renaming *often* renames both. Apparently the registry can be temporarily modified if that suits your need.

A quick alternate could be **NET USE**. At least this takes the label of the folder you are mounting instead.

> Ps. **NET USE** must point to a *network share* eg:

```
NET USE v: '\\localhost\c$\Temp'
```

^^ This will create a new `V:\` drive called `Temp` ... assuming this folder exists (and the administrative share is available).

Answer (score 1):

just a little addition to the originally accepted answer :

```
NET USE v: '\\localhost\c$\Temp' /persistent:yes
```

(this will keep the mount even if pc restarted.)

```
NET USE v: /delete
```

(to remove the mount)

and if your system explorer is grouped by something,

then right click>remove grouping>set to none

set sorting to sort by>name